# How To Make an Advanced Loading Bar in Sony Vegas

Tags: vegas-pro, adobe, transitions

Using Photoshop and Sony Vegas I Have Made a Simple Loading Bar and I Want To Upgrade it. Basically I Want To add a Spark animation To The Top of The Bar That Moves With it until it Loads Completely, I Thought That only Timing Would be The Problem and I could Just use a Push Transition but it doesn't Seem So, Any Ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you illustrate or post an image of what the bar with the spark looks like?

Comment: Sure, Here is a Picture of The Loading Bar about Halfway, and The Spark Animation Where it Should Be When The Bar is Halfway

Comment: Just So That You Know. The Loading Bar is an Image and The Spark is a Video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the spark footage has an alpha channel, as is likely, then make sure, it is activated - right-click on the event, launch Properties, and check that Alpha Channel in the Media tab is set to Straight.

Now, animate the Spark's position in its Pan-Crop window to track the leading edge of the bar.

---

Offhand, I don't know if you parent a track, is the parent's Pan/Zoom inherited by the child tracks. Try it out. For Track Motion, it is, but that reduces the resolution of the footage pre-compositing to fit the project dimensions, so I avoid it.